# Querying musicbrainz database for obtaining an artist and a work

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am newbie to SQL queries.

I am trying to create a query based on both artist and work of the artist in musicbrainz database.

For example:

If I use

```
SELECT * 
FROM artist 
WHERE NAME::text ILIKE '%beethoven%';
```

it will return the list of artists whose name have `“beethoven”` in their name.

Also if I use

```
SELECT * 
FROM work 
WHERE NAME::text ILIKE '%rammenta%';
```

this will return works which have `“rammenta”` as part their name.

In reality, `"Ah, rammenta", WoO 99 No. 6` is the work of `Ludwig van Beethoven`. I need to get this complete work name and the corresponding artist name if a part of artist name and work name is given as input. Is it possible to query like this?

The link between artist and work is like

[image]

**artist table**

```
artistid|name
```

**work table**

```
workid|name
```

**l_artist_work table** (shown as image)

```
entity0|entity1
```

entity0 is artistid

entity1 is workid

**Update**

```
select
    w.id,
    w.name work_name,
    a.id,
    a.name artist_name
from 
    work w
INNER join l_artist_work l 
on l.entity1=w.id
INNER join artist a 
on l.entity0=a.id
```

Using this query, I connected all required columns but how to search for a particular artist and work from this list

Comment: This wont work because artist and work are in two different tables

Comment: Memo to self, don't comment before coffee.

Comment: Where are you getting that schema diagram? I don't see that relationship here [Schema](https://wiki.musicbrainz.org/images/5/52/ngs.png).

Comment: https://wiki.musicbrainz.org/MusicBrainz_Database/Schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select artist.name, work.name
from artist
inner join l_artist_work
ON artist.id=l_artist_work.entity0
inner join work
ON l_artist_work.entity1=work.id
where artist.name::text ILIKE '%beethoven%' and work.name::text ILIKE '%rammenta%'
```

Comment: Glad you got it worked out. FYI, `name::text` is redundant.